# Map foreign key in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I've been looking around for a long time trying to figure this one out. Take the following example (note that classes and tables shown below are stripped down for simplicity):

```cs
public class UserAccount
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class UserAccountAuthenticationHistory
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // This is the foreign key.
    public UserAccount UserAccount { get; set; }

    public int Code { get; set; }
}
```

Here are my tables:

```sql
-- Pretty simple user account table.
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserAccount]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [Username] NVARCHAR(13) CONSTRAINT [DF_UserAccount_Username] DEFAULT('') NOT NULL,
    [Password] NVARCHAR(60) CONSTRAINT [DF_UserAccount_Password] DEFAULT('') NOT NULL
)

-- And another pretty standard table.
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserAccountAuthenticationHistory]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [UserAccountId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER CONSTRAINT [DF_UserAccountAuthenticationHistory_UserAccountId] NOT NULL,
    [Code] INT CONSTRAINT [DF_UserAccountAuthenticationHistory_Code] DEFAULT(0) NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (UserAccountId) REFERENCES [UserAccount](Id)
)
```

When setting up the mapping/configuration in EF Core using fluent mapping (`IEntityTypeConfiguration`) how should I define this relationship? Further more, what is this relationship called? Is it one-to-*none*?

I've looked throughout stack overflow and a few other places but have been unsuccessful in getting the desired results. I don't want to use any magic conventions that EF Core can provide (such as using the `virtual` keyword or adding a `UserAccountId` property to `UserAccountAuthenticationHistory).

### UPDATE

I *think* I've resolved this by doing what's shown below. However, an explanation as to what's going on and why this works would be s

```cs
public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserAccountAuthenticationHistory> builder)
{
    builder
        .HasOne(x => x.UserAccount)
        .WithMany()
        .IsRequired(true);

    builder.Property(x => x.Code)
        .HasDefaultValue(0)
        .IsRequired(true);

    base.Configure(builder);
}
```

Comment: @Dai above I said that I stripped things down - I'm currently hashing and salting using BCrypt.

Comment: Okay, carry on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured this out for myself. If you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.referencenavigationbuilder.withmany?view=efcore-7.0) link from MSDN and take a look at the `collection` parameter you'll see the following:

> The name of the collection navigation property on the other end of this relationship. If null or not specified, **there is no navigation property on the other end of the relationship**.

However, the remarks section seems to describe further information that looks on the surface a little confusing:

> Note that calling this method with no parameters will explicitly configure **this side of the relationship to use no navigation property, even if such a property exists on the entity type.** If the navigation property is to be used, then it must be specified.

At the end of day, in this case no collection is being used (so it really isn't a *one to many relationship*; it's simply just a foreign key that refers to a particular `UserAccount`.

Below, you'll find code taken from my question above that has seemed to resolve my issue.

```cs
public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserAccountAuthenticationHistory> builder)
{
    builder
        .HasOne(x => x.UserAccount)
        .WithMany()
        .IsRequired(true);

    builder.Property(x => x.Code)
        .HasDefaultValue(0)
        .IsRequired(true);

    base.Configure(builder);
}
```

A further update to this is that sometimes a property might be `null` depending on how the data is [loaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/). This was something I overlooked, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your naming fits exactly what EF likes.

In UserAccountAuthenticationHistory you add

```
public int UserAccountId {get;set;}
```

and in UserAccount you add

```
public virtual ICollection<UserAccountAuthenticationHistory> UserAccountAuthenticationHistories { get; set; }
```

And EF figures it all out.

Comment: I would prefer not to use `virtual` or add another property. I'd like to keep my models separate and not require conforming to a convention that another ORM (such as Dapper) doesn't need.